# Every $k$th Fibonacci generating function

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

To get the generating function of $F_n$, I use the basic recurrence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$.

I think the same approach will work for $F_{kn}$. For example,
$$F_{2n} = 3F_{2(n-1)} - F_{2(n-2)}$$ 
$$F_{3n} = 4F_{3(n-1)} + F_{3(n-2)}$$

from [A001519](https://oeis.org/A001519) and [A014445](https://oeis.org/A014445). I conjecture for any $k$: 
$$F_{kn} = aF_{k(n-1)} + bF_{k(n-2)}$$

How can I find $a$ and $b$? My ideas were to try Binet's Formula (though that requires dealing with irrational numbers) and the matrix form

$$A^n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$ so that 
$A^{kn}  = aA^{k(n-1)} + bA^{k(n-2)} $.

Since $A$ is invertible this is equivalent to $A^{2k} = aA^k + bI$. Maybe this can be solved from here?

Comment: Just computing a few terms it seems $a_k = (-1)^{k+1}$ and $b_k= 1,3,4,7,11,\ldots$ so $b_k$ satisfy the Fibonacci recurrsion $b_{k+1} = b_k + b_{k-1}$ with $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binet's formula states that $F_n=\alpha\tau^n+\beta\tau'^n$
where $\tau=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ and $\tau'=\frac12(-1+\sqrt5)$.
Here it's immaterial what $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are.

Therefore
$$F_{kn}=\alpha(\tau^k)^n+\beta(\tau'^k)^n.$$
The recurrence for $F_{kn}$ has characteristic equation
$$(X-\tau^k)(X-\tau'^k)=X^2-(\tau^k+\tau'^k)X+\tau^k\tau'^k.$$
But $\tau^k\tau'^k=(-1)^k$ and $\tau^k+\tau'^k=L_k$, the $k$-th
*Lucas number*. ($L_0=2$, $L_1=1$, $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$).

Therefore
$$F_{kn}=L_kF_{k(n-1)}-(-1)^kF_{k(n-2)}.$$

Comment: How did you obtain the characteristic equation?

Comment: No, I hid that in the $\alpha$ and $\beta$. @lhf

Comment: I just found out this is listed as the "multiple-angle recurrence" on Mathworld http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html